# Meu dataframe pula uma linha no excel quando columns recebe mais de uma linha (pandas)

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, dataframe

Estou tentando fazer dataframes e passá-los para o excel, mas quando eu faço um dataframe com mais de uma linha de cabeçalho, ele pula uma linha antes de plotar os dados na planilha (deixa uma linha vazia). Parece que o problema está atrelado ao fato do meu argumento *columns* ser uma lista de listas, porque isso não acontece em dataframes onde columns é uma lista única.
Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como resolver isso, tirar essas linhas vazias?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, file_name, spaces):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter')
    row = 0
    for dataframe in df_list:
        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheets, startrow=row, startcol=0)
        row = row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 1
    writer.save()
    
array1 = [['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 6),columns=array1)

array2 =[[1, 2, 3], ['Sharon', 'Nick', 'Bailey'],[22,23,24]]
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(array2, 
            names =('Number', 'Names', 'Ages')) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3),columns=midx)

array3 = ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two']
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 6),columns=array3)

df_lista = [df1, df2, df3]
multiple_dfs(df_lista,'Frames','Frames.xlsx',4)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muda alguma coisa se colocar `row = 1`?

Comment: Ele começaria a imprimir os dataframes a partir da segunda linha da planiha

Comment: Sim, exatamente. Eu entendi que o problema é que está pulando uma linha entre o cabeçalho e os dados. Mas, você tentou `row = 1`?

Comment: Acabei de tentar, não funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você achou ou **nó** que precisa ser desatado pelo pessoal do [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas).

É uma questão de escolha deles. Embora não seja um `bug`, o resultado é como se fosse.

Este, somente é percebido quando se tem como nome de colunas o tipo `MultiIndex`.

Veja abaixo o porque isso acontece:

### Caso 1 - visualmente um bug

```
m = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,1),(1,2)])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=m)
df.to_excel('Frames.xls', sheet_name="Frames", startrow=0, startcol=0)
```

[image: Resultado Caso 1]

### Caso 2 - começando a entender o problema

```
m = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,1),(1,2)], names=['linha 1','linha 2'])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=m)
df.to_excel('Frames.xls', sheet_name="Frames", startrow=0, startcol=0)
```

A modificação foi a inclusão de `names` para as colunas

[image: Resultado do caso 2]

### Caso 3 - O motivo do problema

```
m = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,1),(1,2)], names=['linha 1','linha 2'])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=m)
df.to_excel('Frames.xls', sheet_name="Frames", startrow=0, startcol=0, index_label="Indices")
```

A modificação foi a inclusão de `names` para as colunas e `labels` para os índices.

[image: Resultado Caso 3]

Perceba que aquela linha em branco no Caso 1 é, na verdade, uma linha reservada para o label do índice.

Parece que eles bateram o martelo para quando as colunas **não** forem do tipo `MultiIndex`, o label do índices fica na mesma linha do nome das colunas e ignora o label das colunas.

### Caso 4 - Descrito acima

```
m = pd.Index([1,2], name="coluna")
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=m)
df.to_excel('Frames.xls', sheet_name="Frames", startrow=0, startcol=0, index_label="Indices")
```

[image: Resultado Caso 4]